# Set a Panel Location to Mouse Position

Tags: c#, winforms, mouse

I'm having a problem, I want set a panel Location to Mouse Pos. Everything was "fine" but this happens:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KdnMZ.gif

I want the panel location to be at the center of the mouse. How I can fix it? I'm using Visual Studio. My code:

```c
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Blocker
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        Panel Selection_Box = new Panel();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            Selection_Box.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
            Selection_Box.Location = System.Windows.Forms.Control.MousePosition;
            Selection_Box.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 159, 227);
            Selection_Box.Size = new Size(70, 70);
            Selection_Box.Name = "Selection_Box";
            this.Controls.Add(Selection_Box);

        }

        private void Form_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) 
        {

            Selection_Box.Location = System.Windows.Forms.Control.MousePosition;

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`System.Windows.Forms.Control.MousePosition` returns the position in screen coordinates.
You need to convert it to client coordinates using [PointToClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.pointtoclient).

```
private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Selection_Box.Location = PointToClient(MousePosition);
}
```